# Zipping CSV file using Java produces zip file with lesser bytes

Tags: java, rest, csv, zip

I've a simple Java code which creates a ZIP file using one CSV file. The code is working fine and produces the zip file just right. But, the zip file size(bytes) are different that the one I create using Windows zipping tool or something like 7zip. I need to know if there is any Java library which can create zip file similar to how windows zips the file.

Background - We send this zip file to a REST API which fails sometimes with 403 - Forbidden error but when we zip the file using windows zipper or 7zip, it works fine. So, I would like to know if there is any way to zip file in Java the way windows/7zip does.

I've tried -

1. Inbuilt Java functions for zipping
2. Apache commons compress
3. zip4j

e.g.

```
Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
        // Create the zip file if it doesn't exist
        env.put("create", "true");

        URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:/C:/temp/test.zip");

        try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {
            Path externalTxtFile = Paths.get("C:/temp/test.csv");
            Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("/test.csv");          
            // Copy a file into the zip file
            Files.copy(externalTxtFile, pathInZipfile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING); 
        }
```

PS. We are still waiting for stack trace details from the API provider but in the meantime, I am looking for something which can generate exact replica of zip file generated by OS e.g. Windows Zipper.

**Update**
I tried setting compression level to 1, 2,3,4,5 it works with all of these. I tried setting 7,8,9 it works again. But with compression level 6, its failing. Any idea what could be the reason? My code runs on Unix OS so I believe 6 is the default level. But no idea how compression ratio might affect here.

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\productcost.zip");
ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(output);
zout.setLevel(5); //1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9 works Level 6 - Fails with 403 Forbidden
Path file = Paths.get("C:\\temp\\productcost.csv");
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);
ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry("productcost.csv");         
zout.putNextEntry(ze);
zout.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
zout.closeEntry();
zout.finish();
zout.flush();
zout.close();
```

Also, if I remove first character from the CSV file or add a character manually at the beginning, the file works fine without any level setting. I don't see any BOM characters in the file.

Comment: What is actual error stack trace on the server? The error `403 - Forbidden error` is just the http response code.

Comment: The in-built ZIP library is quite matured and compatible. I use it for years without any problems. So you should investigate the real reason for that error. When the error occurs, is the ZIP file still valid? Can you verify it with 7-Zip? If yes, then the problem is not the ZIP file format. If not, the ZIP file may be corupted otherwise. But your code to create the ZIP file looks fine (it's almost an exact copy of the [Oracle Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) ).

Comment: You can try [ZipOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) instead, but it is likely the same code behind. As an alternative you can e.g. call the 7-Zip command line tool as an external process but then you loose the platform independency.

Comment: @vanje Yeah. I have already tried every possible variant for creating zip file. The service fails to consume it sometimes. I also tried using apache comms compress 7zip methods which again works fine, but the files fails to process through the API.

Comment: @DuncG At the moment, I don't have much details from the service provider. So wanted to check if there is a way to generate zip file exactly similar to how windows zip file is generated.

Comment: @DuncG I've updated the question with recent findings, any ideas?

Comment: Getting the actual error from server is best place to start, but failing that you could try to see the effect of changing the compression levels between 1..9. Unfortunately ZipFileSystem does not appear to support this in `env`, so you'd need to switch to ZipOutputStream and call `zos.setLevel(x)` for futher tests.

Comment: @DuncG Yeah, already updated my question. Its working with 1-5 and 7-9 but not with default 6. Also, I see that it works fine if I remove first character from the CSV file or add a character manually to the beginning. Looks like something related to BOM. But I dont' see any BOM charactcers in the file. :(

Comment: Maybe it works differently when you remove `REPLACE_EXISTING`. But it is more likely that the code sends a Content-Length of the unzipped file or such. (Even though you seem experienced, and a zip file system is sooo good to see). F12 in the browser

Comment: @Techidiot Ignore my last comment - I'd not read your full update on my small screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an bug/issue with the endpoint API which was failing to decompress some of the zipped files with default compression level of 6. The same files were processing through with any other compression level. Since we don't own it, we don't know what exactly did they fixed. But, everything is working fine now. Will update this answer if I hear back from the API providers.

Answer (score -3):

You are not really creating a zip file, you are creating a file with the `.zip` extension and simply copying to it the original CSV file value.

For creating a zip in Java you can follow [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress)

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong here - `FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)` creates a ZIP file system and Files.copy works into ZIP filesystem paths.